# slide should take place from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working on a hide-and-show functionality. I have two bugs in my code:

1. When I click the second div, the content is opening from down to top. How to make it from top to bottom?
2. When I click first it opens but when I click back first it does not close. How to fix it?

Providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/33/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#firstRadio").click(function() {
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#secondRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#thirdRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv, #secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Fixed the second problem of yours. The first one is CSS-related and I have to get outta here lol. Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/39/)

Comment: @antithesis it is the /39. Just changed some hide/slow for `toggle()`